# Angular 8: router.navigate, skip state change but keep "history step"

Tags: angular

I want to prevent users to navigate back to some forms (or even send their link). For this I am using `skipLocationChange: true` on that particular router navigation. The route of the form can have parameters (as an id, to edit an item) or no parameters (then an item is created).

Of course, the problem comes when using `location.back()` from the form. 
Because the form is not in the history, the app thinks it's in the previous view, and so rewinds one more view.

Is there a way to tell the app it's in a new (empty) state? Only to be used while in the form view? So that by going back, it goes to previous view? But when used a few views later, it just skips the form?

Comment: Is form view a single view or does it include route changes? "But when used a few views later, it just jumps the form?", do you mean "jumps to the form" or "skips the form"?

Comment: The route to the form can include parameters (as an id when editing an item) or nothing when creating a new item. And yes, with “jumps the form” I meant “skip the form”. Thank you, I’m editing the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope there is a better solution, because this feels kinda hacky.

Remove the skipLocationChange setting and add a guard to the form route instead. The guard asks a service if the requested route is enabled. Before navigating to the route, enable the route. In the form, disable the route onDestroy, to block future navigation to the route.

- Clicking navigation back inside the form: Navigates to previous route
- Clicking navigation back after leaving the form: Guard navigates to fallback route
- Copying the url and open in new browser: Guard navigates to fallback route
- Refreshing the browser: Guard navigates to fallback route

**my-form.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyFormService {
  public enabled = false;
}
```

**my-form.guard.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyFormGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private myFormService: MyFormService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.myFormService.enabled) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/fallback-route'])
    return false;
  }
}
```

**my-form.component.ts**

```js
export class MyFormComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(private myFormService: MyFormService) {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myFormService.enabled = false;
  }
}
```

**other.component.ts**

```js
export class OtherComponent {
  constructor(private myFormService: MyFormService, private router: Router) {}

  navigateToForm() {
    this.myFormService.enabled = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/path-to-form']);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution might be hacky but it certainly does the job! I can add the fallback route through an extra property into the service to easily re-use this solution everywhere in the app. Anyway, I already made a component just for the routerlinks. With means that it’s only that file I need to adapt to get the expected result.  Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear that. You could also use location.back() inside the guard, to navigate to the previous route. But you have to check if the history is empty with window.history.length and use the fallback route if its empty.

Comment: ok, thx. At the moment it works fine like this, but I take it in account if I meet future problems.